# remove 2 consecutive lines

Tags: python, regex, linux, ubuntu, sed

I have data in the following format:

```
#@ <id_wxyz_1>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_123>
A line written after this one also.

#@ <id_wxyz_2>
One more line.

#@ <id_yex_9>
Another line.
```

Now I want to remove 2 lines: the lines which contain "wxyz" in #@ <...> and its following line. The example output which I want is:

```
#@ <id_123>
A line written after this one also.

#@ <id_yex_9>
Another line.
```

Is there some linux command which can also achieve the same or is there some efficient way in python to achieve the same. I know I can selectively remove a single line using grep, sed, etc. But is it possible to selectively remove 2 consecutive lines by using linux command

EDIT: The answers given are excellent but they do not work for the input of the following form:

```
#@ <id_wxyz_1>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_wxyz_2>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_wxyz_3>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_wxyz_4>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_wxyzadded5>
A line written after this.
```

For the above input I should get no output lines.

EDIT again: another set of inputs which I have is:

```
#@ <id_wxyz0>
Line 1.
#@ <id_wxyz1>
line 2.
#@ <id_wxyz2> 
line 3.
#@ <id_wxyz3> 
line 4.
#@ <id_6>
line 5.
```

For which the output should be

```
#@ <id_6>
line 5.
```

Comment: Consider also using [GNU awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)...

Comment: You can write a Perl script that scans each line for the pattern `_wxyz_`and then deletes the line and the next line. There is no single unix "command" that can do such a thing. I recommend Perl over utilities such as sed or awk when it comes to operating on multiple lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using sed by, eg.

```
/^#@ <.*wxyz.*>/ {
   N        #Add the next line to the pattern space
   s/.*//   #clear the line
   N        #Read another line
   /^\n$/ d #if line was blank, delete and start next cycle (reading again)
   D        #Otherwise, delete up to newline, and start next cycle with that

}
```

Note: For the second case, it still actually outputs a single blank line

Comment: Your answer is awesome. +1 for that. But it does not work for certain inputs as mentioned in the question

Comment: @JannatArora: Fixed (though it's not as simple now, sadly). btw, if the case truly was 2 consecutive lines, and you were using GNU sed, you could do `/^#@ <.*wxyz.*>/,+1 d` instead of this mess.

Answer (score 2):

You can also simply use `grep`.

Example: given your input

```
$ cat t
#@ <id_wxyz_1>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_123>
A line written after this one also.

#@ <id_wxyz_2>
One more line.

#@ <id_yex_9>
Another line.

#@ <id_wxyz_1>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_wxyz_2>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_wxyz_3>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_wxyz_4>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_wxyzadded5>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_wxyz0>
Line 1.
#@ <id_wxyz1>
line 2.
#@ <id_wxyz2> 
line 3.
#@ <id_wxyz3> 
line 4.
#@ <id_6>
line 5.
```

you can run

```
$ grep -A1  --group-separator=""  -P '#[^_]*((?!wxyz).)*$' t
#@ <id_123>
A line written after this one also.

#@ <id_yex_9>
Another line.

#@ <id_6>
line 5.
```

The regexp matches lines starting with `#` and not containing `wxyz`, with a Perl-like syntax (hence the `-P` argument). The `-A1` adds one line after the match to the output. The undocumented `--group-separator=""` options replaces the default `--` that normally separates groups of lines when using the `-A` (or `B` or `-C`) option. Note that this later option is not available on all implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you could say:

```
awk '/^#@ <.*wxyz.*>/{getline;getline}1' filename
```

EDIT: As per your modified question, you can say:

```
sed '/^#@ <id_wxyz.*/,/^$/d' filename
```

Comment: Hi this does not work for input of the form: #@ <id_wxyz_1>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_wxyz_2>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_wxyz_3>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_wxyz_4>
A line written after this.

#@ <id_wxyz_5>
A line written after this.

Comment: @JannatArora It seems that your input has changed.  Comments don't preserve newline; it's be better if you updated your question instead.

Comment: @JannatArora The `sed` option suggested might work for you; see edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it doesnot work for input of the form as i have mentioned in my question (edit again)

Comment: The awk should be `getline;next`, the line after could match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) too. When it matches the line, use `getline` twice for two following lines and use `next` to avoid printing them.

```
awk '/^#@[[:blank:]]+<.*wxyz.*>/ { getline; getline; next } { print }' infile
```

It yields:

```
#@ <id_123>
A line written after this one also.

#@ <id_yex_9>
Another line.
```

---

**UPDATE** to provide a solution for the new edit of the *OP*:

```
awk  '
    BEGIN { RS = "#@" } 
    $1 ~ /[^[:space:]]/ && $1 !~ /<.*wxyz.*>/ { 
        sub(/\n[[:blank:]]*$/, "")
        print RS, $0 
    }
' infile
```

And with your last example it yields:

```
#@  <id_6>
line 5.
```

Comment: Your answer is awesome. +1 for that. But it does not work for certain inputs as mentioned in the question

Comment: too many `getline`s. You only need one (and `{print}` could be `1`).